How to mock the behavior of FileReader while doing Unit testing in Junit5
I have a service class which tries to read the content of CSV file and saves it to Database.
I am trying to mock this behavior in Junit 5 and whatever I pass I am just getting error message as FileNotFound Exception. Even hardcoding the system path is also not working for me. Someone please help.
Implemntation:
   public List<Map<String, String>> readTheCSVFile() {
            List<Map<String, String>> failedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                    new FileReader(filePathDTO.getFilePath()) //filePathDTO.getFilePath() reads the file path like C:\\Documents\\csvFile.csv from application.properties
{
                String[] nextLine;
                reader.readNext();
                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    saveToDoDB(nextLine, failedEntries);
                }
            } catch (IOException | CsvValidationException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return failedEntries ;
        }

Junit test case:
@Test
    public void readCSVFileTest() throws IOException {
        Mockito.when(new FileReader("C:\\Documents\\csvFile.csv")).thenReturn(null);
        when(fileReader.read()).thenReturn(65);
        csvReaderService.readCSVFile();
    }


This question gets asked quite often here. Your code is written in a way that does not allow to supply the unit under test with the configured mocks. You have only 2 options: 1. Refactor to make the code testable, or 2. Mock the construction of every FileReader, mockito supports this since 3.5.something. If the code in question is the real code, not a simplified version to reproduce the issue, I advise you to choose the first option.

Mockito mocks are object based. If you want to Mock a certain Type, you need to created a Mock [or spy] object of this type and use it in your service class:
class CsvService{

    private FilePathDto filePathDto;

    public CsvService(FilePathDto filePathDto){
        this.filePathDto=filePathDto;
    }

    protected CsvReader getCsvReader(){
        return new CsvReader(new FileReader(this.filePathDto));
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> readTheCSVFile() {
        List<Map<String, String>> failedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        try (CsvReader reader = getCsvReader())
        {
            String[] nextLine;
            reader.readNext();
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                saveToDoDB(nextLine, failedEntries);
            }
        } catch (IOException | CsvValidationException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return failedEntries ;
    }
}

@Test
public void readCSVFileTest() throws IOException {
    CsvReader reader = Mockito.mock(CsvReader.class);
    doReturn(65).when(reader).readNext();
    CsvService csvReaderService = Mockito.spy(CsvService.class);
    doReturn(reader).when(service).getCsvReader();

    csvReaderService.readCSVFile();
}


Then make it protected for this example... It's a show case how he can achieve a proper mock and to clarify that he has to use an accessible object in order to mock something.

It's not the best practice, but... it works (package private would work as well). I would add clarification though, that the test must be in the same package (under src/test naturally) as the service, in order to mock the method.
